# WCFM for Woocommerce - list all products of a certain vendor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I didn't find it anywhere.
I need to get all the products belonging to a certain vendor via a **raw SQL query**.
I know both the vendor slug or id, but I couldn't figure out exactly the relationship between the products and a vendor.

Can anyone share a complete SQL to do that or at least what is that relationship between tables.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I used on one of my sites:

*Note: Replace the $vendor_id with the ID of the vendor you have.*

```
$vendor_products_list  = $WCFM->wcfm_vendor_support->wcfm_get_products_by_vendor($vendor_id, 'publish', array('posts_per_page' => -1) );
if ($vendor_products_list){
    foreach($vendor_products_list as $the_product){
        echo $the_product->ID;
    }
}
```

**Note: It is not recommended to do RAW SQL in WordPress. Try to stick to the standard methods available to get desired output.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code suggestion! I'll try it soon and reply here how it went.
 
But in my case it doesn't apply I think, cause I need to do it from an external script, written even in another language, say python. So how would this code help?
So, I completely agree that this is the way WP should be used, but in this case what do we do? :)
Besides, I've done quite a few updates before in raw SQL and it definitely works. You just need to know how WP uses the DB and yes, try to mimic its actions as detailed as possible...

Answer (score -1):

I tried it and it works, thanks! :)
One problem is that obviously you don't have access to the WP functions from an external script/language, but I found a solution that I share here too.

You can include the WP function with this line

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

So I created a PHP file where I used the above code and I generated a json structure with all the information I needed.
Then I can access that from any external script/language.
It's not raw SQL, but it does that job.

Hope this solution helps someone that needs this.